# Create XML from xml using XSLT code

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xsd

```
    <MemoPad>
       <ENTRYTYPE>ReviewFees</ENTRYTYPE>
       <ENTRYDATETIME>2017-09-05</ENTRYDATETIME>
       <USERID>admin</USERID>
      <MEMOENTRY>Review fees test</MEMOENTRY>
    </MemoPad>
    <MemoPad>
       <ENTRYTYPE>UnderwriterReview</ENTRYTYPE>
        <ENTRYDATETIME>2017-04-12</ENTRYDATETIME>
         <USERID>ADMIN</USERID>
         <MEMOENTRY>Underwriter Rule</MEMOENTRY>
    </MemoPad>
     <MemoPad>
          <ENTRYTYPE>UnderwriterReview</ENTRYTYPE>
          <ENTRYDATETIME>2017-09-05</ENTRYDATETIME>
          <USERID>admin</USERID>
          <MEMOENTRY>month bank statement. </MEMOENTRY>
     </MemoPad>
```

I tried a lot writting XSLT for above portion but couldnt crack it down. What I am looking for is basically I want to iterate over each memopad item and in memopad for each EntryType I would like to create an xml like

```
      <ReviewFeesType>
           <ReviewFee>               
                <ENTRYDATETIME>2017-09-05</ENTRYDATETIME>
                <USERID>admin</USERID>
                <MEMOENTRY>Review fees test</MEMOENTRY>
           </ReviewFee>
       </ReviewFeesType>
```

but now for entry types which are multiple type should be created as below.

```
     <UnderwriterReviewType>
        <UnderwriterReview>
            <ENTRYDATETIME>2017-04-12</ENTRYDATETIME>
            <USERID>ADMIN</USERID>
            <MEMOENTRY>Underwriter Rule</MEMOENTRY>
        </UnderwriterReview>
         <UnderwriterReview>
             <ENTRYDATETIME>2017-09-05</ENTRYDATETIME>
             <USERID>admin</USERID>
             <MEMOENTRY>month bank statement. </MEMOENTRY>
           </UnderwriterReview>
     </UnderwriterReviewType>
```

How can i write an XSLT for this? 
Please help.

What I have tried is

```
   <MemoPads>
      <xsl:for-each select="MemoPad">            
        <xsl:element name="{ENTRYTYPE}">
          <ENTRYDATETIME>
            <xsl:value-of select="ENTRYDATETIME"/>
          </ENTRYDATETIME>
          <USERID>
            <xsl:value-of select="USERID"/>
          </USERID>
          <MEMOENTRY>
            <xsl:value-of select="MEMOENTRY"/>
          </MEMOENTRY>
        </xsl:element>            
      </xsl:for-each>
    </MemoPads>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am novice to XSLT

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is your XSLT that you did?

Comment: Hello Anton, I have updated my question to give you a bit more idea

Comment: It is tricky in general to answer questions about fragmentary code and / or data, and it is especially tricky for XSLT and other XML technologies relying on XPath.  Present a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  If you are uncertain what an MCVE is, then do *follow the link* to find out what we expect in that regard.

Comment: So you want to group the `MemoPad` elements by `ENTRYTYPE`, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#grouping-examples

Comment: Or if you are using XSLT 1.0 (one of the many things that might be cleared up by an MCVE) then [Muenchian grouping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT/Muenchian_grouping) may be your best way forward.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your time. Yes Grouping worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `grouping` example. If you are using `XSLT 1.0`, a `<xsl:key>` needs to be declared.

```
<xsl:key name="kEntryType" match="MemoPad" use="ENTRYTYPE" />
```

The input XML provided is not well-formed as it does not contain `root` node, hence I have assumed that `<MemoPads>` is the `root` node. The below XSLT will help in getting the desired output. The comments should help understand the logic.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- declare a grouping key -->
    <xsl:key name="kEntryType" match="MemoPad" use="ENTRYTYPE" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- create root node in output -->
        <MemoPads>
            <!-- loop for all the groups based on the declared key -->
            <xsl:for-each select="//MemoPad[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kEntryType', ENTRYTYPE)[1])]">
                <!-- create parent element for the grouped elements -->
                <xsl:element name="{concat(ENTRYTYPE,'Type')}">
                    <!-- loop through the set of elements within the key -->
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('kEntryType', ENTRYTYPE)">
                        <!-- create element as required in the output -->
                        <xsl:element name="{ENTRYTYPE}">
                            <!-- copy all elements except the ENTRYTYPE -->
                            <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::ENTRYTYPE)]" />
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </MemoPads>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<MemoPads>
    <ReviewFeesType>
        <ReviewFees>
            <ENTRYDATETIME>2017-09-05</ENTRYDATETIME>
            <USERID>admin</USERID>
            <MEMOENTRY>Review fees test</MEMOENTRY>
        </ReviewFees>
    </ReviewFeesType>
    <UnderwriterReviewType>
        <UnderwriterReview>
            <ENTRYDATETIME>2017-04-12</ENTRYDATETIME>
            <USERID>ADMIN</USERID>
            <MEMOENTRY>Underwriter Rule</MEMOENTRY>
        </UnderwriterReview>
        <UnderwriterReview>
            <ENTRYDATETIME>2017-09-05</ENTRYDATETIME>
            <USERID>admin</USERID>
            <MEMOENTRY>month bank statement. </MEMOENTRY>
        </UnderwriterReview>
    </UnderwriterReviewType>
</MemoPads>
```

Comment: Hello Aniket..This is genius..It worked perfectly. However I am wondering about XSD now. Do we write xsd for such tricky XSLT's?

Comment: I am not very sure about XSDs since the output XML contains certain elements that are dynamically created. You may want to put it up as a different question for experts to answer.